# Как сделать вывод в таблице разделяя строки по датам?

Tags: php

Есть обычная таблица в ней есть поле дата (лишний столбик занимает).

Хотелось бы сделать так

29 декабря  2016

- строка 1 заявка за 29 декабря
- строка 2 заявка за 29 декабря
- строка 2 заявка за 29 декабря

28 декабря  2016

- строка 1 заявка за 28 декабря
- строка 2 заявка за 28 декабря
- строка 2 заявка за 28 декабря

т.д.

Код у меня щас такой:

```
$result_lead = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  lids WHERE id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."'$delet_status ORDER BY $sort_date DESC LIMIT 20" ,$db);
if ($result_lead > 0) {
do {
 // тут выводим лиды
} while ($myrow_lead = mysql_fetch_array($result_lead));
}
```

Дата добавления хранится в формате `2016-12-29 14:59:20`

Comment: либо сгруппируйте массив после выборки из БД и выводите двойным циклом, либо при выводе проверяйте дату текущей строки и предыдущей. Если разные, то вставляйте доп.строку с датой.

Comment: @teran я бы так сделал, но не знаю как =/ пытаюсь найти, пока не нашел решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так:

```
    <?php
    $result_lead = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  lids WHERE id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."'$delet_status ORDER BY $sort_date DESC LIMIT 20" ,$db);
    $currDate = null;
    if ($result_lead > 0) {
        while ($myrow_lead = mysql_fetch_array($result_lead)) {
            $date = $myrow_lead['date'];
            if ($date !== $currDate) {  //если нашли отличную дату - выводим новым блоком
                $currDate = $date;
                echo $currDate;
                $i = 0;
            }

            echo "строка " . ++$i . " заявка";
        }
    }
```

Comment: благодарю, отличное решение.